# Relation between QTransform scale and boundingRect.size()

Tags: c++, qt, scale, qgraphicsitem

I have little concern about what is relation between QTransform scale and width and height return values in boundingRect() method of QGraphicsItem.
Actually I want to scale QGraphicsItem as its boundingRect size. i.e. if size of my item initially 100,100 that I am passing in boundingRect() method after that I am increasing the size of item by mousemove event. If my increased width and height is 400,300 respectively is my scale factors 4,3?
Any help will be appreciable.

This is code

```
this->setPos(minMax().first.x(), minMax().first.y());


qreal w = minMax().second.x() - minMax().first.x();
qreal h = minMax().second.y() - minMax().first.y();

qreal scaleFactorW = w / boundingRect().width();
qreal scaleFactorH = h / boundingRect().height();

QTransform trans;
trans.scale(scaleFactorW, scaleFactorH);
setTransform(trans);

bottomPoints = QPointF(w, h);
```

minMax function is:

```
float xMin = 0, xMax = 0, yMin = 0, yMax = 0;
QList<double> xValues, yValues;
xValues << shaper[0]->scenePos().x() << shaper[1]->scenePos().x() << shaper[2]->scenePos().x() << shaper[3]->scenePos().x() << shaper[4]->scenePos().x() << shaper[5]->scenePos().x() << shaper[6]->scenePos().x() << shaper[7]->scenePos().x();
yValues << shaper[0]->scenePos().y() << shaper[1]->scenePos().y() << shaper[2]->scenePos().y() << shaper[3]->scenePos().y() << shaper[4]->scenePos().y() << shaper[5]->scenePos().y() << shaper[6]->scenePos().y() << shaper[7]->scenePos().y();
qSort(xValues.begin(), xValues.end());
qSort(yValues.begin(), yValues.end());
xMin = xValues.first();
xMax = xValues.last();
yMin = yValues.first();
yMax = yValues.last();
return qMakePair(QPointF(xMin, yMin), QPointF(xMax, yMax));
```

shaper is qgraphicsitem by which I am resizing item.

Thanks :)

Comment: Take into account that `boundingRect()` method returns the bounding rectangle in item coordinates, so it is not affected by transformations such as scale.

Comment: I wonder what is faster... to write such a question here on SO and wait for a response, or write two lines of code and test it yourself.

Comment: @Greenflow Problably the best way to solve the problem is playing with the code.

Comment: Yes I am playing with code but its like trial and error method

Comment: @Zing It'd be easier to answer if you put your code.

Comment: There is no relation between boundingRect() and Scaling. You can have a Rectangular GraphicItem with size as 100x100 but boundingRect as 500x500. This will **NOT** scale the item. Please Read the documents thoroughly !!!!

Comment: @Pratham can we ralate them as per I moving by shaperitem using scale method. I did by changing the boundingRect values i.e. args that boundingRect returns?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for showing your code.

As I said before,

`trans.scale(scaleFactorW, scaleFactorH);`

won't change the size returned by `QGraphicsItem::boundingRect`.

But in fact, `QGraphicsItem::setScale` has the same behaviour and the `boundingRect()` for the item doesn't change either.

QTransform::scale and QGraphicsItem::setScale are not the same, but both are useful to change the image size. Well, in the case of QTransform, you're scaling the coordinate system.

I think an example is the best way of explaining myself.

(`this` inherits `QGraphicsItem`)

```
qWarning() << "QGraphicsItem::scale(): " << this->scale();
QRectF br = this->boundingRect();
qWarning() << "QGraphicsItem::boundingRect() size / x / y / w / h: " << br.size() << " / "
                                                        << br.x() << " / "
                                                        << br.y() << " / "
                                                        << br.width() << " / "
                                                        << br.height();

QTransform trans = this->transform();
trans.scale(2.0, 2.0);
this->setTransform(trans);

/*
     Comment trans.scale(2.0, 2.0) and uncomment the following line
                to check the difference using the logs.
*/

// this->setScale(2.0);

qWarning() << "QGraphicsItem::scale(): " << this->scale();
br = this->boundingRect();
qWarning() << "QGraphicsItem::boundingRect() size / x / y / w / h: " << br.size() << " / "
                                                        << br.x() << " / "
                                                        << br.y() << " / "
                                                        << br.width() << " / "
                                                        << br.height();

qWarning() << "boundingRect * item_scale: " << this->boundingRect().size() * this->scale();
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please, use `QGraphicsItem::setScale` as far as possible.

Comment: but this method has one argument. I want to change both height and width and ratio could be different

Comment: OK then :) Enjoy coding!